# How to estimate operation cost/business model of Multi-Party Computation (MPC)

Tags: multiparty-computation

As the director of a privacy-preserving startup venturing into *Multi-Party Computation (MPC)* protocol development, we are faced with the challenge of finding the most suitable business model.

Our potential clients emphasize the requirement of not sharing their data outside their network. Subscription-based pricing seems suboptimal due to the diverse sizes of our clients.

We believe that resource usage for computation, given that it occurs at the data owner's side, might be a key metric.

However, we are uncertain about estimating operational costs.

**What would be the most effective business model for our startup considering these factors, and how can we accurately estimate the operational costs given the computation occurs at the data owner's side?**

Comment: Besides being off-topic (this is a site for cryptography Q&A, not for business model Q&A), I put "give me a profitable idea and business plan for a startup, for free" in the same category as "do my homework for me."

Comment: Upon reflection, my comment was a little harsh. In the spirit of being constructive, the OP could improve the question by asking a question specifically about what is known about estimating MPC performance/operational costs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that it is easy for you to answer with high accuracy.

You did not disclose the nature of the input / output data,
the computation, or chosen MPC scheme, which rather complicates
matters when random internet strangers attempt to answer with
high accuracy.

> how can we accurately estimate the operational costs given the computation occurs at the data owner's side?

Just benchmark a [PoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept).
Choose an MPC scheme and code it up, hopefully by using existing libraries.
Obtain several hosts, one per party.
Run the computation and measure the resource usage.

For added realism, obtain separate accounts from, for  example, AWS.
Use one account per party.
An effective business model will require
verifying that the charges for *your* party are
less than what other parties are willing to pay you.